# double click on window title bar do not resize back from zoomed window in mac os sonoma 14.0

Tags: macos

with macSo v Sonoma 14.0 Beta (23A5301g)

When I click on any window , it Zoomed as I have below settings

> Dock Settings > Double-click a window's title bar to --> Zoom

but when double click on zoomed window then then it do not resize to previous. after looking solutions , tried to reset this settings ( select None and again back to Zoom)but this solution did not work.

it seems a bug in this macOS version, as in earlier version it was working and I was using it heavily.

someone suggest me what and how to fix ( without using any 3rd party tool/utility)

Comment: Report it to Apple. That's why you got the beta, to find & report bugs.